# Как присвоить одному объекту класса все аргументы другого?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если брать переменные, допустим, у меня есть x и y, я хочу переменной x присвоить значение y, я просто пишу

x = y

Как сделать тоже самое с объектами класса?

Вот мой класс

```
class Calculator:

def sum(self, x, y):
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    self.z = x + y
    self.act = "sum"
    print(self.z)

def sub(self, x, y):
    self.z = x - y
    self.act = "sub"
    print(self.z)

def mul(self, x, y):
    self.z = x * y
    self.act = "mul"
    print(self.z)

def div(self, x, y, mod=False):
    if not mod:
        self.z = x / y
        self.act = "div"
        print(self.z)
    if mod:
        self.z = x % y
        self.act = "mod"
        print(self.z)

Op0 = Calculator()
Op1 = Calculator()
Op2 = Calculator()
```

Это калькулятор, который умеет выполнять 4 арифметических действия. Когда нужно выполнить действие, объекту Op0 - операция будут присваиваться соответствующие аргументы.

```
@cli.command("sum")
@click.argument("x")
@click.argument("y")
def sum_cli(x, y):
    Op0.sum(x, y)
```

Но мне надо сохранять историю операций, поэтому я добавил еще 2 объекта операций, и в функцию выполнения действия пишу такой код:

```
def sum_cli(x, y):
    Calculator.Op2 = Calculator.Op1
    Сalculator.Op1 = Calculator.Op0
    Calculator.Op0 = Calculator(x, y)
    Op0.sum(x, y)
```

Но это неправильно, он видит класс Calculator, как объект. А как правильно написать?

Comment: покажите ваши классы и лучше объясните что вам надо сделать.

Comment: Еще до того, как увидел комментарий, решил так сделать, вот, показал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а если сохранять историю операций просто в списке, например `transaction_history` ?

```
class Calculator:

    def sum(self, x, y):
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        self.z = x + y
        self.act = "sum"
        print(self.z)
        return self.act, x, y                   # ++

    def sub(self, x, y):
        self.z = x - y
        self.act = "sub"
        print(self.z)
        return self.act, x, y                   # ++

    def mul(self, x, y):
        self.z = x * y
        self.act = "mul"
        print(self.z)

    def div(self, x, y, mod=False):
        if not mod:
            self.z = x / y
            self.act = "div"
            print(self.z)
        if mod:
            self.z = x % y
            self.act = "mod"
            print(self.z)

Op0 = Calculator()
transaction_history = []                            # ++

#@cli.command("sum")
#@click.argument("x")
#@click.argument("y")
def sum_cli(x, y):
    transaction_history.append(Op0.sum(x, y))       # ++
    
sum_cli(3, 4)   

# Но мне надо сохранять историю операций, 
    
op = Op0.sub(3, 4)                                  # ++
transaction_history.append(op)                      # ++

print(transaction_history)                          # ++
```